# AngularJS- how to change value of dynamic model

Tags: angularjs

I want to  change `{{order.status}}` to `def` when someone click `updatestatus` button.

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
<!--
<div ng-model="row[order.id]" >abc</div>
-->
<div ng-model="row[order.id]" >{{order.status}}</div>

<a href="#" ng-click="changestatus(order.id)">updatestatus</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Controller

```
$scope.row = {};
$scope.changestatus = function(id) {
    //console.log(id);
    $scope.row[id] = 'def';
}
```

It does not work. Please help.

Comment: `ng-model` is not meant for div, only form controls. Read the docs

Comment: Thanks. I know there is an error (should not use div with ng-model). But my main issue was to change the current value{{order.status}} when some one click updatestatus. I have updated my post(kept the div error for reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ng-model` here. `ng-model` is used for `inputs`, `textarea`, `select` or `custom form elements` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <div>{{ row[order.id] }}</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="changestatus(order.id)">updatestatus</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here, you just need to update the view. For this `ng-bind` is used https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

`<div> ng-bind="row[order.id]"></div>` and `<div>{{ row[order.id] }}</div>` are similar

**UPDATE**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <div>{{ order.status }}</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="changestatus(order)">Update Status</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changestatus = function(order) {
    //console.log(order.id);
    order.status = 'the update status'; // status changed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will change the div. However, my issue was changing the current status. Please check my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It works now. PS. I assume, "$scope.row[order.id] = 'def' was typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{row[order.id]}}` instead of `abc` in your view and remove `ng-model` within your `div`.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <div>{{ row[order.id] }}</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="changestatus(order.id)">updatestatus</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <div ng-bind="row[order.id]"></div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="changestatus(order.id)">updatestatus</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```